# Getting a recursion error when connecting a pyqtgraph linearregionitem with a plotitem's axis

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to do something similar to what is done in the pyqtgraph example 'Crosshair/Mouse Interaction'.  Basically I want to connect a linear region item on one plot, to the x-axis on another plot.  then one plot will show the data that's in the linearregionitem, and you can zoom in and out by changing the linearregionitem, and vice-versa.

My problem is that it crashes with:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a
>   Python object

Here is the code from the example if you want to try it to give you an idea of what I want to do...

```
"""
Demonstrates some customized mouse interaction by drawing a crosshair that follows 
the mouse.


"""
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
from pyqtgraph.Point import Point

#generate layout
app = QtGui.QApplication([])
win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
win.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: crosshair')
label = pg.LabelItem(justify='right')
win.addItem(label)
p1 = win.addPlot(row=1, col=0)
p2 = win.addPlot(row=2, col=0)

region = pg.LinearRegionItem()
region.setZValue(10)
# Add the LinearRegionItem to the ViewBox, but tell the ViewBox to exclude this 
# item when doing auto-range calculations.
p2.addItem(region, ignoreBounds=True)

#pg.dbg()
p1.setAutoVisible(y=True)


#create numpy arrays
#make the numbers large to show that the xrange shows data from 10000 to all the way 0
data1 = 10000 + 15000 * pg.gaussianFilter(np.random.random(size=10000), 10) + 3000 * np.random.random(size=10000)
data2 = 15000 + 15000 * pg.gaussianFilter(np.random.random(size=10000), 10) + 3000 * np.random.random(size=10000)

p1.plot(data1, pen="r")
p1.plot(data2, pen="g")

p2.plot(data1, pen="w")

def update():
    region.setZValue(10)
    minX, maxX = region.getRegion()
    p1.setXRange(minX, maxX, padding=0)    

region.sigRegionChanged.connect(update)

def updateRegion(window, viewRange):
    rgn = viewRange[0]
    region.setRegion(rgn)

p1.sigRangeChanged.connect(updateRegion)

region.setRegion([1000, 2000])

#cross hair
vLine = pg.InfiniteLine(angle=90, movable=False)
hLine = pg.InfiniteLine(angle=0, movable=False)
p1.addItem(vLine, ignoreBounds=True)
p1.addItem(hLine, ignoreBounds=True)


vb = p1.vb

def mouseMoved(evt):
    pos = evt[0]  ## using signal proxy turns original arguments into a tuple
    if p1.sceneBoundingRect().contains(pos):
        mousePoint = vb.mapSceneToView(pos)
        index = int(mousePoint.x())
        if index > 0 and index < len(data1):
            label.setText("<span style='font-size: 12pt'>x=%0.1f,   <span style='color: red'>y1=%0.1f</span>,   <span style='color: green'>y2=%0.1f</span>" % (mousePoint.x(), data1[index], data2[index]))
        vLine.setPos(mousePoint.x())
        hLine.setPos(mousePoint.y())



proxy = pg.SignalProxy(p1.scene().sigMouseMoved, rateLimit=60, slot=mouseMoved)
#p1.scene().sigMouseMoved.connect(mouseMoved)


## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

If you don't want to read all that, the linearregionitem and the plotitem are connected via the lines...

```
def update():
    region.setZValue(10)
    minX, maxX = region.getRegion()
    p1.setXRange(minX, maxX, padding=0)    

region.sigRegionChanged.connect(update)

def updateRegion(window, viewRange):
    rgn = viewRange[0]
    region.setRegion(rgn)

p1.sigRangeChanged.connect(updateRegion)
```

---

---

Here's a minimal working example of my code...I'm doing pretty much the same thing, but I'm doing it in a class...

When you run it, it will crash if you adjust the linearregionitem, or if you change the axis of plotA.  If you comment out either of the 'connect' lines, then the program will work (half-way).

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys

# PyQt5 includes
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication


class MyApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__buildUI()


    def __buildUI(self):

        plotWidget = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()

        self.PlotA = pg.PlotItem()
        self.PlotA.setXRange(10, 20)


        self.PlotB = pg.PlotItem()
        self.PlotB.setXRange(0, 100)


        self.lri = pg.LinearRegionItem()
        self.lri.setRegion((10, 20))
        self.PlotB.addItem(self.lri)

        # The following two connections set up a recursive loop
        self.lri.sigRegionChanged.connect(self.update)
        self.PlotA.sigRangeChanged.connect(self.update_lri)

        plotWidget.addItem(self.PlotA)
        plotWidget.nextRow()
        plotWidget.addItem(self.PlotB)

        self.setCentralWidget(plotWidget)

        self.show()


    def update(self):
        minX, maxX = self.lri.getRegion()
        self.PlotA.setXRange(minX, maxX)


    def update_lri(self, window, viewRange):
        A_xrange = viewRange[0]
        self.lri.setRegion(A_xrange)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    widget = MyApplicationWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What's happening? Can anyone tell me how to get this working?  This is in Python 3.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

+1 for proving a good [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This allowed me to experiment a bit and I found the issue. Couldn't have solved it without it.

You must set the padding to zero when updating the x range of the plot. So change the `update` method to:

```
def update(self):
    minX, maxX = self.lri.getRegion()
    self.PlotA.setXRange(minX, maxX, padding=0)
```

Typically with QT these infinite signal loops are prevented by only updating a variable (and emitting the corresponding signal) when the new value is different from the old value. Somewhere in Qt/PyQtGraph this check is also done. But since your padding isn't zero, the new xrange will be a little bigger than the old xrange every iteration, and the loop doesn't end.

BTW, it is common in Python to let variable names start with a lower case character, and class names with upper case. I recommend to rename `self.PlotA` to `self.plotA`. This makes your code better readable for other Python programmers. Also it will give better syntax highlighting here on Stack Overflow.